# Using AsyncDataStream and RichAsyncFunction with SingleOutputStreamOperator

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I'm aggregating over a keyed stream using a `SingleOutputStreamOperator` object in the form

```
stream = env.fromSource(...)...sideOutput(...).window(...).aggregate(...)
```

After I obtain the aggregates I would like to send each record to a REST endpoint using a POST request. To do this I've written a `RichAsyncFunction`. Unfortunately `AsyncDataStream.unorderedWait(...)` is incompatible with `SingleOutputStreamOperator` and instead needs a more generic `DataStreams` object.

```
The method unorderedWait(DataStream<IN>, AsyncFunction<IN,OUT>, long, TimeUnit, int) in the type AsyncDataStream is not applicable for the arguments (SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple6<String,String,Long,Long,Long,Long>>, AsyncFunction<String,String>, long, TimeUnit, int)
```

How can I use get the data stream from `SingleOutputStreamOperator` to use the `RichAsyncFunction` I've created. Or should I just use a process window function instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SingleOutputStreamOperator<T>` extends `DataStream<T>`, so I don't think that's your problem.

It looks like you've defined an `AsyncFunction<String,String>`, so it expects a `String` as input, but based on the error message you're passing it `Tuple6<String,String,Long,Long,Long,Long>`.

Comment: Ah yes you're right! I was able to change the types. Am I right in thinking that the `AsyncFunction` I've defined will take in each streamed input into the function and process each element?

Comment: There's good documentation about how Async IO works at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/asyncio/